# Windows User Account that executes only IIS7 Provisions

Tags: iis-7

I have a web application that executes IIS 7 provisions (using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll) to create our web and ftp sites. When I run this using the administrator account, it works ok.

I want to create a Windows user account for impersonation that will only execute these web provisioning procedures without being identical to a server's administrator roles.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Forgot to say that I'd also recommend using Named Pipes for any communication between your Trusted Wrapper assembly and the WCF/Remoting app. It reduces the attack surface a bit by not having TCP/IP ports listening. And I'd also stick some additional authentication in the service application as well, e.g. pass a username/password for each privileged operation and have some kind of custom authentication mechanism, say against a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split your application into three parts:

**Windows Service**

This would host a WCF or Remoting application. You want to put the code that requires privileged access to your system in here. For example creating and deleting websites. Run this service under an account that has enough rights to perform operations using `Microsoft.Web.Administration`.

**Trusted Wrapper or Proxy Assembly**

This is just a signed wrapper assembly that is installed in the GAC. Its role is to pass on calls from your low trust web application to perform privileged actions in the code running in the service above. Mark the assembly with the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute (if your server is configured for partial trust) and mark any classes that require access to the remoting service with `[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted=true)]`.

**Front End Application(or Web Service)**

This is the interface to your application (whether it be a web application with a GUI or a web service). Run this in its own application pool with just enough rights to execute, for example `IUSR` or a similar account. Ideally you should also run this under partial trust.

Your web application/service references the Trusted Wrapper assembly in the GAC which in turn has a reference to the remoting or WCF application running in the windows service.

Using this layered approach means that you are locking down by gating access to specific privileged operations which only run in your windows service.

This approach is covered quite well in Appendix C of Dominick Baier's '[Developing More-Secure Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623317)'. I thoroughly recommend getting a copy.